# why the drawn model is not centered in the screen

Tags: c++, opengl, translate-animation

I'm loading an `Obj model` and am trying to draw it like this :

```
void Game::Update()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(Color::CornflowerBlue.R, Color::CornflowerBlue.G, Color::CornflowerBlue.B, Color::CornflowerBlue.A);
    gluPerspective(45.0, 800.0 / 600.0, 1.0, 1000.0);



    DrawModel(model);
}

void DrawModel(const Model &model)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < model.Faces.size(); i++)
    {
        if (model.Materials.size() > 0)
        {
            float diffuse[] = { model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Diffuse[0], model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Diffuse[1], model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Diffuse[2], 1.0 };
            float ambient[] = { model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Ambient[0], model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Ambient[1], model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Ambient[2], 1.0 };
            float specular[] = { model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Specular[0], model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Specular[1], model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Specular[2], 1.0 };
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
            glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, model.Materials[model.Faces[i].Material].Ns);
            glColor3f(diffuse[0], diffuse[1], diffuse[2]);
        }

        int loop = 3;
        if (model.Faces[i].IsQuad){
            loop = 4;
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        }
        else
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

        if (model.NormalVertices.size() > 0)
            glNormal3f(model.NormalVertices.at(model.Faces[i].Index).X, model.NormalVertices.at(model.Faces[i].Index).Y, model.NormalVertices.at(model.Faces[i].Index).Z);
        for (int j = 0; j < loop; j++)
        {
            //TODO TEXTURE:
            if (model.Vertices.size() > 0)
                glVertex3f(model.Vertices[model.Faces[i].VerticesIndex[j]].X, model.Vertices[model.Faces[i].VerticesIndex[j]].Y, model.Vertices[model.Faces[i].VerticesIndex[j]].Z);
        }

        glEnd();
    }
}
```

but I can't see it , because it's not centered in the screen , I know that I can `translate` it's coordinates , but I want it to show the model in the center without translating how is that possible?

Comment: And what does `DrawModel` exactly?

Comment: @LittleHelper I have updated the question with the `DrawModel` function.

Comment: Is your model designed with its center at (0,0,0)?

Comment: For the most part, the odd transform (such as `glTranslatef`) here and there are free. They all get combined into a single matrix anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try [gluLookAt()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) to place the "camera" and tell it where to look at.

You always translate the models to make them visible on screen because only the geometry rendered in the unit cube gets drawn to screen. Using gluLookAt() and gluPerspective() only generates fitting matrices to translate the geometry in the defined frustum to the unit cube.

It seems like you are learning OpenGL. If that is the case I would recommend not learning the old (<3.0) way with glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES) etc. but learn the new (>=3.0) OpenGL version, with VertexArrayObjects and the like, right away. For a start I can recommend this site: [OpenGL Tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/)